Using bucket_sort based on top_hits aggregation
I'm trying to implement bucket sorting based on top_hits aggregation results.
Example of aggretions configured in query
        "top_order_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "id": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": "id"
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "top_order_hits._source.id": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "gap_policy": "insert_zeros",
            "from": 0,
            "size": 25
          }
        }
      }

Executing this query returns an error
Validation Failed: 1: No aggregation found for path [top_order_hits._source.id];
I've also tried top_order_hits.sort this results to another error
path not supported for [top_order_hits]: [sort]**
Is there any way to use bucket_sort over top_hits?

What is the type of id? This could be a job for top_metrics instead
